# Инициализация массива в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Привет.

Когда я создаю массив

```
var thingsv = new Array(length)
```

у меня нет возможности, проинициализировать его начальными значениями, потому что формы вызова

```
var thingsv = new Array(length, value)
```

в языке нет (я не нашел). Приходится в цикле бежать по массиву и заполнять его. Нет ли более удобного способа?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так можно инициализировать массив из 10 элементов, каждый из который символ `*`:

```
Array(10).join('*').split('')
```

Answer (score 4):

*Предисловие*

---

Конструкции `new Array(length, value)` в JS нет, в связи с тем, как работает конструктор `Array()`. Если он принимает одно значение как аргумент, допустим, `length`, и `typeof length == 'number'` (приведение типов здесь работать не будет, даже `.valueOf()` у объекта не будет вызываться), тогда создастся пустой массив, заполненный чем-то непонятно, из `length` элементов.

Можно даже заметить, что в разных браузерах в консоли это будет по-разному выглядеть, в общем так просто оставлять это не желательно. Но когда это условие не выполнено, то создаётся массив, элементами которого будет всё, что указано в аргументах конструктора.

Кстати, запись `Array()` и `new Array()` ничем не отличается. И для инициализации пустого массива лучше (браузеру от этого приятнее) писать `var mas = []`, а не `var mas = Array()`.

*Акт первый*

---

К сожалению, нативное заполнение всего массива целиком появилось совсем недавно, с приходом ES6, и ещё плохо поддерживается браузерами, но как факт существует:

```
Array(1000).fill(-1);
```

Данная конструкция заполнит всю тысячу элементов массива значением `-1`. Плюс, как фишка, в функции можно задавать с какого по какое значение заполнить. Полное описание работы этой функции и её полифилл можно найти [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

*Акт второй*

---

Забавы ради можно предложить ещё один способ, появившийся в ES6. Будем использовать функцию `Array.prototype.from()`, она тоже не очень поддерживается браузерами, но немного лучше, чем `Array.prototype.fill()`:

```
Array.from({length: 1000}, () => -1);
Array.from({length: 1000}, function() { return -1; }); // аналогично
```

Она принимает два объекта. *Array-like* объект (что-нибудь, что имеет свойство `length`), а вторым, функцию для вызова на каждый элемент нового массива (фактически будет выполнен неявный `.map()`). Подробное описание и полифилл можно посмотреть [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

*Акт третий*

---

С появлением ES5 заполнить массив стало возможно при помощи функции `Array.prototype.map()` вот так:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 1000}).map(function() {return -1});
```

Либо если пошутить и добавить щепотку ES6, то можно и вот так:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 1000}).map(() => -1);
```

Думаю надо немного расжевать. `Array.prototype.map()` проигнорирует все пустые значения новоявленного массива (помните, я писал, что там что-то непонятное), поэтому надо сделать их явными. Делаем мы это так: `Array.apply(null, {length: 1000})`. В качестве контекста не имеет значения что передавать, а как аргумент вполне передадим *array-like* объект. Для итерирования по элементам необходимо только поле `length`, а так как элементов нет, то значениями всегда будет `undefined`. Метод рабочий, но лучше так не писать.

*Акт четвертый*

---

Можно сделать это по старинке, сначала выполнив `Array.prototype.join()`, соединив все элементы в строку, а затем `Array.prototype.split()`, разделив массив на атомарные сущности.

```
Array(1000).join('-1').split('');
```

Плюс в том, что работает везде. Минус, в том, что заполнить массив можно только текстовыми значениями, как следствие необходимо выполнять приведение для получения чисел и всё-таки это медленно.

*Акт пятый, для справедливости*

---

Думаю надо написать и про самый проверенный и быстрый из ныне существующих методов заполнения массивов данными:

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    array.push(-1);
}
```

Более быстрая и удобная его реализация:

```
var array = Array(1000);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; array[i++] = -1);
```

*Заключение*

---

Выбирать способ заполнения массива данными (как и собственно всё остальное) всегда надо с умом, а я просто приведу небольшое сравнительное тестирование скорости выполнения всех операций на [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/array-default-init/2). Осторожнее, на старых браузерах часть тестов работать не будет.

Comment: `array[i++] = -1`

Comment: @Qwertiy, точно, спасибо